# Conditions for positive and negative - Beyond "Reduce" - How can this be attacked?

Tags: equation-solving

Unfortunately, the following attempt to find the conditions for positive does not work. There is a solution for 0, but the condition for negative is bothersome too.

```
Assuming[(n | vi | Vq | Vd | Q | Bd | Bq | Subscript[b, q]) \[Element] Reals && n >= 2 && vi > 0 && Vq > 0  && Vd >= 0 && Q >= 1, FullSimplify@Reduce[-((n^2 (-1 + 2 n) (Q ((Bd + Bq)^2 - vi) + vi + Vq - \!\(\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(j = 1\), \(Q\)]\*SuperscriptBox[\((Bd + bi + Bq - \*SubscriptBox[\(b\), \(j\)])\), \(2\)]\)))/((Bd + bi + Bq)^2 (-1 + n)^2 Q + Q (Vd + vi + Vq) - 2 n Q (Vd + vi + Vq) + n^2 (vi + Vq - \!\(\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(q = 1\), \(Q\)]\*SuperscriptBox[\((Bd + bi + Bq - \*SubscriptBox[\(b\), \(q\)])\), \(2\)]\)))^2) > 0]]
```

Any suggestions about how to attack this problem to find conditions, nevertheless? Or am I resigned to not finding general expressions?

Comment: Replace Q by some integer, then Reduce[ % , Reals] with released assumptions yields answer, from which you have a chance to see how Q value affect the answer (look at denominators for different Q values).

Comment: @user18792, could I persuade you to attempt an answer?